File attachment in OSB 12C HTTP service
I am attempting to build a HTTP service to send form-data in a POST call through OSB 12C. There are a few text parameters and an attached file that I am testing from Postman.

I added an HTTP Transport proxy service of type Binary request and Text response as well as a business service of the same type. The external service returns a simple string containing "Ok" or "Error ...". I had also tried with a Text request and response types.
I then added a pipeline with a log action (for a break point) and empty route.
The break point shows me attachments for the form data fields, but nothing for the "File" field. Where is this? Furthermore, the content header shows that the content length is only 700 bytes even though the file I am trying to attach is 15KB in size.
The attachments would be PDF files and I don't need to inspect or change their contents in OSB.
Edit: Progress.
If I attach a txt file, it does show up in the parameters collection. The content is shown in the value field. This means that OSB is discarding anything that cannot be converted to valid XML. Hmm...
